# Convergence of infinite $ \sum (\frac{n}{n+1})^{n^2} $?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, convergence-divergence

I have being trying to solve this convergence but with no success. Using the ratio test I have reached here:

$$ 
a_n = \left( \frac{n}{n+1} \right)^{n^2}
$$

And

$$ 
\frac{1}{a_n} = \left( \frac{n+1}{n} \right)^{n^2}
$$

Also

$$ 
a_{n+1} = \left(\frac{n+1}{n+2}\right)^{{(n+1)}^2} = \left(\frac{n+1}{n+2}\right)^{n^2+2n+1} = \\ a_{n+1} = \left(\frac{n+1}{n+2}\right)^{n^2} \cdot \left(\frac{n+1}{n+2}\right)^{2n} \cdot \left(\frac{n+1}{n+2}\right)
$$

Therefore

$$
\lim \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \lim \frac{1}{a_n} \cdot a_{n+1}  = \\
\lim \left[ \left( \frac{n+1}{n} \right)^{n^2} \cdot \left(\frac{n+1}{n+2}\right)^{n^2} \cdot \left(\frac{n+1}{n+2}\right)^{2n} \cdot \left(\frac{n+1}{n+2}\right) \right]
$$

And I dont know how to go any further, I have tried many possibilities none of them reaching any result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of the ratio test, try the root test:

$\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty}|a_n|^{1/n} = \lim_{n \to \infty}\left|\left(\dfrac{n}{n+1}\right)^{n^2}\right|^{1/n} = \lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\dfrac{n}{n+1}\right)^{n} = \lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n+1}\right)^{n}$

Do you recongnize this limit?

Comment: Indeed. $ \frac{1}{e} $. It's very stupid when we are stuck with something in our head and we try to solve using harder methods when we should just give one step back and try other tools. Thank you for this simple answer.

Answer (score 0):

The Bernoulli inequality proves that the sequence $\{a_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}^+}$ defined by:
$$ a_n = \left(1+\frac{a}{n}\right)^n $$
is an increasing sequence converging towards $e^a$. By taking $a=-1$, this gives that your series is positive and bounded by:
$$\sum_{n\geq 1}e^{1-n} = \frac{e^2}{e-1}.$$